# How to stop an animation of a single child from a group g svg?

Tags: animation, svg

I am currently trying to stop the animation of a single child in a group g that has an animation.

So I tried to isolate the child and give him a class css to stop the animation, but he seems to ignore it and privilege his father's classes.

Is it possible to force a child not to apply a specific class of his father?

```css
.pulsBlockly {
    animation: pulsBlockly 1s ease-out 0s infinite alternate;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

@keyframes pulsBlockly {
    0%   { opacity: 0.4; }
    100% { opacity: 0.1 }
}

.nopulsBlockly {
    animation: none !important;
    -webkit-animation: none !important;
    -moz-animation: none !important;
    -o-animation: none !important;
    -ms-animation: none !important;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <g class="pulsBlockly">
    <g class="nopulsBlockly">
      <rect rx="4" ry="4" x="-5" y="0" height="16" width="27.35" fill="gold"></rect> 
      <text class="blocklyText" y="12.5">&nbsp;∅&nbsp;</text>
    </g>
  </g>
<svg>
```

As expected, the first group g is animated as I wish, but the second group g flashes when I do not wish.

Answer (score 0):

The `opacity` property is different from most other properties.  It does not inherit down to child elements.  Instead, it causes the creation of an isolated layer which is drawn at the specified opacity.  Anything in that layer - for example all of the group's children - will be affected by that opacity.  There isn't anything you can do to get around that.

If you have a group of animated things, and you want some of them to be animated, and some not.  Then you will need to apply the animation to each child individually.

For example, you could move the animation to each child using the CSS `>` (direct child) combinator.

```
/* Applies to any direct child of `pulsBlockly` */
.pulsBlockly > * {
    animation: pulsBlockly 1s ease-out 0s infinite alternate;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

If you do this, the `nopulsBlockly` class on a child will cancel it's animation.

```css
.pulsBlockly > * {
    animation: pulsBlockly 1s ease-out 0s infinite alternate;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

@keyframes pulsBlockly {
    0%   { opacity: 0.4; }
    100% { opacity: 0.1 }
}

.nopulsBlockly {
    animation: none !important;
    -webkit-animation: none !important;
    -moz-animation: none !important;
    -o-animation: none !important;
    -ms-animation: none !important;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <g class="pulsBlockly">

    <g><!-- gets animated -->
      <rect rx="4" ry="4" x="-5" y="0" height="16" width="27.35" fill="gold"></rect> 
      <text class="blocklyText" y="12.5">&nbsp;∅&nbsp;</text>
    </g>

    <g class="nopulsBlockly" transform="translate(40,0)"> <!-- nopulsBlockly blocks the animation this time -->
      <rect rx="4" ry="4" x="-5" y="0" height="16" width="27.35" fill="gold"></rect> 
      <text class="blocklyText" y="12.5">&nbsp;∅&nbsp;</text>
    </g>
  </g>
<svg>
```